# How do I disable a button once it's pressed, then re-enable it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to disable the button once I have pressed it on my page. Then when I go into the favourites page and delete the item from there, the button should reappear but I do not know how to do it.

Could I get some help please?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#add_btn").on("tap", function(){
        var propName = $("#propName").text();
        var propPrice = $("#propPrice").text();
        var pageURL = $(location).attr("href");
        localStorage.setItem("propName", propName);
        localStorage.setItem("propPrice", propPrice);
        localStorage.setItem("prop", pageURL);
        $('#pFave').html("Property added to Favourites");
        $("#popupFave").popup("open", "reposition", 'positionTo: window');
    }); 

    var propLength = window.localStorage.length;
    console.log(propLength);
    if(propLength !=0){
        var hName = localStorage.getItem("propName");
        var hPrice = localStorage.getItem("propPrice");
        var url = localStorage.getItem("prop");
        var list = "<li><a href='"+ url +"' data-ajax='false'>" +hName +"<br> "+hPrice + "</a><button id='remove' class='ui-btn ui-corner-all'>Delete</button></li>";
        $('#listProperties').append(list).listview('refresh');
        $('#remove').on("tap", function(){
            localStorage.removeItem("propName");
            localStorage.removeItem("propPrice");
            localStorage.removeItem("prop");
            window.location.reload();
        });
    } else {
        var list = "<li data-icon='false'><a href='#' data-ajax='false'>No Properties Saved</a></li>";
        $('#listProperties').append(list).listview('refresh');
    }
});
```

```html
<div data-role="popup" id="popupFave" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:300px;">
                <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                    <h3 id='pFave'> </h3>
                    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all " data-rel="back">Ok</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button id="add_btn" data-icon="star">Add to favourites</button>
```

Comment: Your question is too broad in my opinion. Please consider editing it in order to underline the points you are really curious about and remove the unnecessary parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the button: `$("#add_btn").attr("disabled", true);`

To enable the button you could to `$('#add_btn').attr("disabled", false);` or `$('#add_btn').removeAttr("disabled");`